# Odd array key/value variable assigning in CURL posting

Tags: php, arrays, curl

Let's say I have an array, and I print it:

```
  print_r($myArray);
  Array
  (

        [post] => 333434kj
        [test] => wOVvc
        [tytytyty] => xyzsalasjf

  )
```

This array gets assigned to a CURL Post:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field1=".$f1."&field2=".$f2."&something=True");
```

Since "field1" is equal to "post" and $f1 is equal to "333434kj", etc., I am having a hard time figuring out how to implement the keys and values as variables, as the [post], [test], and [tytytyty] change values for every time this runs.  How do I make each key a variable and each value a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://php.net/http_build_query

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($myArray) . "&something=True");
```

You can also just pass the array instead if you wish:

```
$myArray['something'] = 'True';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myArray);
```